# php comparing a string that contains an &

Tags: php, mysql

Ok here's the thing

I have a jump menu, and when the user chooses an option from the menu and jumps to the page that filters the search results, I want the jump menu to show the selected search

So they choose option 'Caribbean' and the page reloads with only those destinations, and hopefully 'Carribean' is shown on the jump menu.

Well yes I can do that.... but some of the destinations are like this

North Cape & Northern Lights

And they don't work..

Here's my code

```
<option value="chooseacruise.php?destination=<?php echo  $row_destinations['destination']?>"<?php if ($_GET['destination'] == $row_destinations['destination']) {echo "selected=\"selected\"";}?>><?php echo $row_destinations['destination']?></option>
```

Help, I've tried lots of things and still the same, it only works if the destination doesn't contain an amphisand

arrghh!

Rich :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `urlencode()` for this purpose. For instance:

```
echo  urlencode($row_destinations['destination']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the `&` as `&amp;`. Check out this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php